# Encoding Node/Postegres SQL_ASCII

Tags: node.js, codificação-de-caracteres, ascii

Tenho uma API em Node que se conecta com um banco PostgreSQL utilizando o módulo "pg", onde o banco em questão usa o encoding "SQL_ASCII". Não tenho a opção de mudar o encoding do banco pois o mesmo é da prefeitura da minha cidade.

Quando faço uma busca em uma tabela/campo que contém caracteres especiais como por exemplo `"Administração"`, tenho o seguinte retorno: `"Administr\\xe7\\xe3o"`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelas pesquisas que andei fazendo descobri que `\xe7` é o codigo Unicode da letra `ç`, inclusive consigo traduzir essa string se utilizo métodos do JavaScript como `decodeURIComponent("\xe7")`,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, a resposta que  tenho é com DUAS barras (`"\\xe7"`), sendo assim, todos os métodos que tentei utilizar nenhum funcionou. Obviamente também tentei fazer o `'\\xe7'.replace('\\\\\', '\\')` para então tentar utilizar o decode, mas não tive sucesso.

Quando coloco essa string em uma página HTML (utf8), ela mostra da seguinte forma: `"Administr\xe7\xe3o"` com 1 barra, sendo que o meu objetivo é mostrar a palavra correta.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você está confundindo as codificações. `%C3%A7` é ç codificado em URI, `xe7` é o apenas o hexadecimal de ç.

Tente dessa forma:

```js
const area = "Administra\\\\xe7\\\\xe3o";
console.log(area);

const area_decod = unescape(area.replace(/\\\\x/g, '%'));
console.log(area_decod);
```

Comment: Funcionou!
Muito obrigado!  me salvasse!

Realmente eu estava confundindo então.

Se não for pedir muito, poderia me explicar esse regex que foi feito? ou algum link onde eu possa aprender mais sobre o mesmo. 

Obrigado!